# How to change the alfresco url using proxy

Tags: proxy, alfresco, reverse-proxy, alfresco-share

I need to change the alfresco explorer and share url using proxy. How to change the url?

My current url is `http://System1:8080/alfresco`, `http://System1:8080/share`

I need to change to `http://kroxx`, `http://wiks`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to configure both servers to produce the correct links. This configuration should go in your `alfresco-global.properties`, making sure that each WAR file accesses its relevant configuration entries:

```
alfresco.context=
alfresco.host=kroxx
alfresco.port=80
alfresco.protocol=http

share.context=
share.host=wikis
share.port=80
share.protocol=http
```

You most likely [need also](https://issues.alfresco.com/jira/browse/MOBILE-42?focusedCommentId=140813&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3acomment-tabpanel#comment-140813) to change your Share configuration in order for CMIS to properly produce links to your public Alfresco URLs. The following goes to your `share-config-custom.xml`:

```
<alfresco-config>
  <config evaluator="string-compare" condition="Server">
    <server>
      <scheme>http</scheme>
      <hostname>kroxx</hostname>
      <port>80</port>
    </server>
  </config>
</alfresco-config>
```

Comment: `<hostname>your-pulic-host</hostname>` what to put in "your-public-host"

Comment: I changed the config to use what you provided in your question. It has to be the publicly visible URL